# Nginx, how to remove headers before caching the request

Tags: caching, nginx, header

I need to remove the headers received from the upstream proxy before storing the request into the nginx cache.

With the following configuration I can see how the headers defined for clear are not deliver to the client, but are stored in the cache path, if I open one of the files located there I can see all.

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/cache levels=1:2  keys_zone=STATIC:1m inactive=1y max_size=50G;
server {

        listen localhost;
        server_name myserver;

        location / {

                more_clear_headers 'Last-Modified';
                more_clear_headers 'Cache-Control';
                more_clear_headers 'Expires';
                more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
                more_clear_headers 'X-AspNet-Version';
                more_clear_headers 'X-Powered-By';
                more_set_headers -s 200 'Cache-Control:  max-age=31557600';

                proxy_pass http://IP;

                proxy_set_header       Host example.com;
                proxy_cache            STATIC;
                proxy_cache_valid      200 301 302 1y;
                proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
                proxy_cache_key $uri;

                add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        }
}
```

Comment: And why you want it?

Comment: I can't rely on the cache times and other options inside the headers ( must-revalidate. for example)

Comment: @Rikr did you find the solution?

Comment: No, sorry... any solution. Good luck!